# I developed a api and i want it to redirect to other php page and pop up the modal as i click the button in api file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

**api.php**

```
$result .="<a  class='  btn btn-primary  ' href='api.php?action=editVarients&id=".$row["id"]."'>Edit</a>";

$result .="<a  class=' edit1 btn btn-warning  ' href='api.php?action=editstock&id=".$row["id"]."'>Add Stock</a>";
```

When I click on edit it redirects to variant.php, where a modal gets, pop up.
TELL ME HOW IS THAT POSSIBLE?

Comment: Can you please show us the api.php file?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question and description, the outcome seems to be exactly what you're wanting.

**Question Heading**

> ...i want it to redirect to other php page...

**Question Body**

> When I click on edit it redirects to variant.php ... TELL ME HOW IS THAT POSSIBLE?

Everything seems to be working fine, unless you could be more specific with the problem you need to solve.